# Windows 10 Defer Upgrades not working

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1703, automatic-update, intune

I'm encountering an issue, where my computers software updates are managed by Intune and the 'Defer Updates' policy is enabled.

Some laptops are however still getting the option to upgrade to the newest Windows 10 Creators Upgrade (15063) - disregarding the Intune agent.

Is this due to Intune not being able to handling Feature Upgrades and only Quality Updates? Shouldn't the 'Defer Updates' policy deter the upgrade?

I'm running OS Version 10.0.1493

Best regards

Comment: You do understand you can only defer features updates for 4 months.  I think you mean `14393` not `1393` since `10.0.1393` doesn't even exist.  1703 became a required update that could no longer be defered in July/August timeframe.

Comment: I was under the impression, it was possible to defer up to 180 days?

And yes, i did mean 14393.

EDIT: Just found a guide which explains how to defer updates up to 180 days, when applied through GPO.
https://www.howtogeek.com/286658/how-to-change-how-long-updates-are-deferred-in-windows-10/

Comment: Even if it was 6 months, that would have ended in Sept, but to my knowledge is 4 months not 6.  Appears the article says otherwise, my understanding the default deferred period was 4 months, looks like in this case it was a configuration issue.  Article says 365 is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Appears the newest ’Windows 10 Creators Update and later …’ wasn't chosen under Admin > Updates > Product Category.